# Deploying to fuji network with hardhat creates HttpProviderError

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, hardhat, avalanche

I am having issue deploying contract to fuji c chain with hardhat. Here is my hardhat.config.js file:

```
const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  networks: {
    fuji: {
      url: 'https://api.avax-test.network/ext/bc/C/rpc',
      chainId: 43113,
      gasPrice: 20000000000,
      accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`],
    },
    avalanche: {
      url: 'https://api.avax.network/ext/bc/C/rpc',
      chainId: 43114,
      gasPrice: 20000000000,
      accounts: [`0x${PRIVATE_KEY}`],
    },
  },
};
```

Here is the command for deploying the contract:
`npx hardhat run --network fuji scripts/deploy.ts`
I am getting the following error:

```
ProviderError: HttpProviderError
    at HttpProvider.request (E:\SolidityProject\Leveor\nft-platform-script\node_modules\hardhat\src\internal\core\providers\http.ts:78:19)
```

I also have used a different rpc url provided by infura with the API key but it gave the same error.
How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was setting the `gasPrice` on the hardhat config file. For the fuji network the gas is automatically calculated and explicitly setting a gas price causes the error `ProviderError: HttpProviderError` (The error message could be better). This is the same case for the Celo network. But for Ethereum, Polygon, and Binance smart chains you CAN explicitly define the gas price.